# Amazon website not loading completely

Tags: amazon, firefox, download, internet-explorer

For the last few months now, I've been having problems with the (German) Amazon website.

One day, the website stopped loading correctly. Since that, my browser (Firefox as well as Internet Explorer) only shows the header of the website in most cases.

When I took a look at the source code of that page, it became obvious that the source code stops somewhere in the middle of the body part. So I can only see the title of the website or the top navigation as well - this varies.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Whenever this happens, I press [F5] time and again in order to refresh the website. I always wait until loading has been finished, and repeat this until the website is shown completely.

What could cause this annoying behaviour? It's only for Amazon's website, I've no problems with Google, Facebook and all other sites that I visit.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148645/discussion-on-question-by-caw-amazon-website-not-loading-completely); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.